# Disclosed information about the operation

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of "***disclose***".  Let's say the context is a spy causing some government covert operation to be known to the public:

> 1. A spy ***disclosed the operation*** to the public.
> 2. A spy ***disclosed information about the operation*** to the public.

Is either version better?  Is "*information about*" necessary?

Comment: **disclose** can imply full revelation, including the details, and so "information about" is not absolutely necessary, though you'll often see a qualifier being used to make the meaning clearer, as in "disclosed the  *whole* operation". The meaning "reveal every aspect (of something)" was far more dominant in the 19th c. than it is now.

Answer (score 1):

"Disclose the operation" means to disclose the existence of an operation that was totally unknown.  The expression doesn't describe the amount of detail released, though.  For example, the spy disclosed that the NSA has an operation called "Phonetap" that secretly records everyone's phone calls.

"Disclose information about the operation" means to disclose specific details about the operation.  For example, the spy disclosed that Operation Phonetap is currently capturing 1 billions calls per week in the US and Europe.

For paranoid readers, I just made up this example.  The NSA isn't really recording your calls.  (or are they?)  :-)